# Can you actually finish Zork in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, zork

..or is it just a cute easter egg?

[context](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jkqk8DjPxN4#t=40s) (bonus points for screenshots)

Comment: Now I'm curious and I already sold my copy. I only loaded it and moved 2 screens or so. It was too much effort to type (not sure if it works with a chatpad) so I gave up.

Answer (score 13):

Well, according to [this walkthrough](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/topic/342671-black-ops-zork-complete/), you can.